# Organizing Terminal profiles in macOS

Tags: macos, terminal

I have well over 100 Terminal profiles, and would like to find some way of organizing them, either using tags or folders. Unfortunately, I don't see any support for this in the Terminal app.

Does anyone have suggestions on how I could accomplish this?

Comment: Try [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/features.html).  It has excellent profile support.